# Calling functions provided by the Activity class from anywhere

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

How do I call the functions provided by Activity class from a class that does not extend Activity? Theoretically, yes, if I don't extend Activity I cannot directly use the functions provided by it. But is there a workaround provided for this? If not, are there replacements or alternative ways for these functions?

For example,
If my class extends Activity, I can call `setContentView()` to instantiate my layout xml file. But if my class extends some other class and doesn't extend Activity, then I can use the LayoutInflater to do the task. But what about other functions like `registerReceiver()` ? How do I get the functionality of '`registerReceiver()`' from any other class , obviously I wouldn't want every such class to extend Activity. Static access by "`Activity.function_name`" is also not possible as these functions are not static.

Certain services can be accessed from anywhere. For example '`println()`' or `Log.e()`,System functions can be called from anywhere, whenever needed. Is there a similar way for other critical functions?

**Conclusion:**

Pass Context to destination class. For accessing some functions however, type-casting the passed Context to Activity is required.

Both Changdeo's and BT's answers are correct.

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass instance of particular activity to non-activity class and use it. MOst of the cases Context will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Sahil Mahajan. Didn't know backquotes do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have not found any documentation explicitly stating why, in every case where I have ever needed to do this, simply passing the `Activity`'s `Context` is sufficient.

For a `Context` called `contextActivity` passed into any function, the following will allow access to these member functions you require:

```
((Activity) contextActivity).<anyMemberFunction>
```

Or if you need these functions in multiple cases it might be simplest just to do the following:

```
Activity myActivity = (Activity) contextActivity;
```

From there you can access these `Activity` member functions whenever you like by using:

```
myActivity.<desiredFunction>;
```

As I mentioned, I have never found any case where this hasn't worked, but also no solid documentation saying this will always work. This is the trick I have seen consistently used though. If anyone has more to add, please do.

Comment: You could always check using `if (context instanceof Activity)`.

Comment: Thanks B T. By passing the context, I could access the functions from my other class. As stated in my comment to Changdeo's answer, I had to  actually type cast the context to Activity to call setContentView().

Comment: No worries, if casting is necessary to achieve the result, then I would think this would be a more correct answer as it is not mentioned in the other (let alone showing how to do it). I may be a touch biased though ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Ex

```
Class XYZActivity extends Activity
{
   ......
    ......
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
    // OR you can pass just context
    // MyClass myClass = new MyClass(getContext());
}

Class MyClass
{
  Context context;
  Myclass(Context context)
  {
   this.context = context;
   context.registe....//Or any function 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Changdeo, that worked. I could access `registerReceiver()` and other functions. But to access `setContentView()` , I had to cast it to Activity class, as suggested by BT's answer. Thanks!